# How do i share images directly to Google photos?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Without raising the share menu?

Also, can I share a bunch of images together?

Thanks !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developers.google.com/photos Google Photos api. Transfer photos easily

Comment: I am a little new in programming... What is this API and how do i use it in android studio?